# List or Collection: which one to use in interfaces?

Tags: java

Assuming that I want loosely coupled interfaces, I often avoid using List implementations (like ArrayList) in method signatures and prefer using the List interface. But as Collection is a more general interface, do you think I should prefer using Collection over List?

**Edit**: I know the difference between List and Collection. I don't care about the order or any List-specific feature. And this question is about return values as well as method parameters.

Comment: The answer is probably not the same if the List/Collection is an argument or the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good API should provide all that is needed without exposing unnecessary implementation details.

I find myself using List or Set the most. Trying to replace List or Set with Collection sometimes makes the API awkward to use without really offering any added decoupling or abstraction.

I try to avoid Maps in method signatures because I think it is a telltale sign that the input/output is too complex. This can be solved by creating a specific wrapper class for this data or by changing the method's location so it has direct access to the data (e.g. putting it in the class that you were passing to the method).

Don't forget your object oriented design is there to make life easier for those maintaining and calling your code, not to achieve some holy grail of perfection. There are usually several sensible ways to model a problem and which one you choose depends on your own style and the expected future complexities/use cases of the code base you are working on.

Comment: +1 for "*Trying to replace List or Set with Collection sometimes makes the API awkward to use*"

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of List (which extends Collection):

> An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.

In a nutshell: List preserves the order of its elements (insertion order or any other order you choose to impose).

So if you care about any of these things, use List.

Comment: If the OP is talking about the return value, this does not answer his question.

Comment: @assylias: Not sure what you mean. I guess you want your return types as specific, and your parameter types as broad as possible.

Comment: I understood his question as `public List<T> m() { return new ArrayList<>(); }` vs. `public Collection<T> m() { return new ArrayList<>(); }`.

Comment: I would choose List, then (if I can guarantee it and it brings benefit). Collection is potentially less useful, but leave more freedom to the implementation (especially considering future updates and subclasses).

Answer (score 2):

I only go as far as `List`, `Set` or `Map`. That gives the caller some indication of what they can expect to get back, without being too specific.

I think having that indication as part of the method signature is important. It can change the way they plan to use the result.

eg. `Collection` doesn't guarantee unique entries like a `Set` would. Returning `List` implies the results will be ordered, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you intend to do.

If order is not important, `Collection` can make sense over `List`.

Generally speaking and as you suggest, it is usually good practice to use a *high-level* interface in your method parameters so that the calling code does need to make any conversion to meet the method requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  The `Collection` interface has a different semantic to `List`.  When you iterate the elements of a `Collection` you have no expectation that the elements are returned in a specific order.  (Indeed for some collection types, the iteration order is practically unpredictable.)

In addition, there are a number of operations that you can perform using the `List` API that you can't do using the `Collection` API.  Such things as getting, inserting or removing an element at a specific position.

Comment: Re: "in addition" These things all follow from having a defined order in the first place, though.